# change position from fixed to absolute when a specific px is left

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am working on a page for a project where there is a button to the left of the screen. (it appears when you scroll down) This button is working just as it should just untill you scroll to the bottom of the screen, then it covers up the copyright. So I was wondering if there are any way to make the button absolute when there is a specific amount of px left till the bottom of the screen.
This is the page http://forexamples.co.nf/eksamen/#

I would prefer if it was possible that way instead of just a specific px on the screen, because I want the height of the screen to match the screen size, therefore the height of the screen will not be a specific amount of px.

Comment: Couldnt find any button in that page

Comment: The button is on the left bottom side, it does not appear before you start scrolling.

Comment: Oh, your were mentioning about that "Move to Top" element ?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would just move either the copyright to the other side of the screen or the scroll to top to the center of the screen. 
That would sort your problem out without too much messing around...

Comment: yes I thought about that myself. and I will do that if I do not find a solution. However I also just got curious, if this was possible? Might be useful in another project sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use two classes in css. One is for fixed and another is for absolute. Then you have to use jquery to remove the first class and add second class. **.removeClass()** and **.addClass()** of jquery.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And yes this would not be too hard if I could say on what pixel it should do so. However I want it to act when there is a specific px left till the bottom, so that it will not change if the screen size change. Do you know a way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try by changing a CSS class:

```
.show {
    left: 0;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```